# leetcode first (the easiest) - two_sum

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

I wanted to practise some algorithms... Why doesn't my solution work on [leetcode website](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/)?!?! 
PS: Would be grateful for other resources to learn algorithms and practise interview questions.

```
# @param {Integer[]} nums
# @param {Integer} target
# @return {Integer[]}
def two_sum(nums, target)
    i,j = 0,nums.length-1
    output = []
    while i < nums.length-1
      while j > i
        if nums[i] + nums[j] == target
            output << i << j
        end
        j-=1
      end
      i+=1
  end
  output
end
```

Result from the website:

Input:
[3,2,4]

6

**Output: []**

Expected:[1,2]

Comment: Also as a challenge, you can solve this algorithm in `O(n)` ;)

Comment: You should state, at the beginning of your question, what you are attempting to do, rather expecting the reader to go to the link to get that information. For one, links can be broken. You could use the first line at the link (modified slightly): "Given an array of integers (the argument `num` below), return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that your question has been answered, I would like to suggest a more Ruby-like method.

**Code**

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  (0...nums.size).to_a.combination(2).find { |i,j| nums[i]+nums[j] == target }
end
```

**Example**

```
nums = [1,5,2,3,4]
target = 8

two_sum(nums, target)
  #=> [1,3]
```

**Explanation**

For the example above, the steps are as follows:

```
a = nums.size
  #=> 5 
b = a.times
  #=> #<Enumerator: 5:times>
c = b.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
d = c.combination(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:combination(2)>
```

We can see the elements that are generated by the enumerator `d` by converting it to an array.

```
d.to_a
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]] 

d.find { |i,j| nums[i]+nums[j] == target }
  #=> [1, 3]
```

Note that `(0...nums.size).to_a` could be replaced by any of the following.

```
[*0...nums.size]
nums.each_index.to_a
nums.size.times.to_a
0.upto(nums.size-1).to_a
Array.new(nums.size) { |i| i }
Array.new(nums.size, &:itself)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you don't reinitialize `j` when it reaches `i` which means that your algorithm just tries `(0,n-1), (0,n-2), …, (0, 2), (0, 1)` and then stops.

Comment: Time Limit Exceeded now :(